# Java void calculating the result from two different methods at main

Tags: java, void

hi i wanted to ask if  i had two public void methods in another class  like these, how can i calculate the result(res+result) the two of these at my main class  ?.I had it for my homework.
thanks for your time.

```
public void method(int x,int y){
double result;
result=x+y;
System.out.println("Result :"+result);}

public void method2(int x,int y){
double res;
result=x+y;
System.out.println("Result :"+result);}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that `method2` will not compile (unless there's a field in the class called `result`) what is the difference between `method` and `method2` supposed to be?

Comment: SO is not a site where you can have answers for your exam or your home work, SO is for developers seeking Answers for problems they are facing for hours/days.

Comment: Nirav Madariya its not about exam or homework its about learning something maybe im not a dev but i have to start from somewhere.You dont wake up a morning and knew everything about programming.How do you know that im not facing this problem for hours or days?? because it seems silly that doesnt mean that i dont try to figure out how to solve it.So none told you to answer me or help me.So stop being like this in ppl who tries to learn something.Just to know http://prntscr.com/fj776e

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are learning, so ideally you should spend a considerable amount of time figuring stuff up for yourself ( Getting the answers might help you pass the class, but won't help you learn )

That being said, Try this:

Create a new class, e.g: util.java

```
public class util {
    public void method(int x,int y){
      double result;
      result = x + y;
      System.out.println("Result :" + result);

    }

    public void method2(int x,int y){
      double res;
      res = x + y;
      System.out.println("Res :" + res);

    }
}
```

And in your main do the following:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        util ut = new util();

        ut.method(2, 2);
        ut.method2(4, 4);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Result :4.0
Res :8.0
```

---

Just for fun, you could also do the following:

util.java

```
public class util {

    private int method(int x,int y){
      return x + y;
    }

    private int method2(int x,int y){
      return x + y;
    }

    public void result(int x,int y){
      System.out.println("Result: " + ( method(x, y) + method2(x, y) ));
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        util ut = new util();

        ut.result(2, 2);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Result: 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, you can't.
Either you have to change return type of methods to void and then calculate. Or, you can make a wrapper class where you'll store both of results and then calculate it in main

Moreover, your code won't compile because you don't have property result in method2 but property res